# SSRS One Page Per Row

Tags: layout, reporting-services, row

I created a new report with a datasource that is returning 100 rows.

In the layout I just drag over a few columns in, no toolbox control. But in preview and deploy I only get one page output with the first row.

What exactly do I need to do so that it renders **One Page Per Row**?

Not sure if it matters, but my data source is a SharePoint list Web service and I'm using a CAML Query to select data. I do see the records in the Data section in design mode.

```
<Query>
   <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
   <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"
           Name="GetListItems">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="listName">
            <DefaultValue>{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}</DefaultValue>
         </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you drag a field onto a blank area of the report, BIDS creates a textbox and then inserts an aggregate function (SUM or FIRST depending on field type, I think.)

It sounds like the best way to get what you want will be to first drag a **List** from the toolbox, then layout your textfields inside the rectangle.

Now insert page breaks by right clicking on the **(Details)** row group (lower pane of BIDS window.) Select **Group Properties**.

In the resulting dialog, go to **Page Breaks** and select the check box for **Between each instance of a group**.